# Apache 2.4 upgrade

Tags: apache, redhat, siteminder

We have upgraded apache2.2  to 2.4  after upgrade siteminder advanced password cgi script is not working and it returning 503 service unavailable webpage. but the same script working via cli. Any idea ?

```
     Alias /siteminderagent/pwcgi/ "/opt/siteminder/webagent/pw/"
     <Directory "/opt/siteminder/webagent/pw/">
     Options Indexes MultiViews ExecCGI
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
     </Directory>
     Alias /siteminderagent/pw/ "/opt/siteminder/webagent/pw/"
    <Directory "/opt/siteminder/webagent/pw/">
     Options Indexes MultiViews ExecCGI
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
     </Directory>
     Alias /siteminderagent/ "/opt/siteminder/webagent/samples/"
     <Directory "/opt/siteminder/webagent/samples/">
      Options Indexes MultiViews
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
     </Directory>
```

Comment: Your formatting makes my eyes hurt. Please format it properly and maybe we can read it better. And what's the associated error?

Comment: What shows in the error log?

Comment: this is cgi script hence i enabled scrpitlog also but nothing there in the scriptlog also

Comment: There are a bunch of changes to apache 2.4. Enable error logging and check the logs again. Make sure you have the correct modules loaded.